# Cron is not running keyboard backlight control script

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, backlight

I am trying to write a script that turns off my keyboard backlight after 30 seconds of inactivity to conserve power.  It needs root permissions to run properly.  In the current attempt, I am implementing it as a Cron job.  The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# requires installation of xprintidle

# if user idle for greater than or equal to 30s and
# keyboard backlight is on, turn backlight off
echo 'Start script' >> /home/lair001/cronout.txt
CheckIdle() {
    if [ 30000 -le $(xprintidle) ] && [ $(cat /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness) -ne 0 ]
    then
    echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
    echo 'Attempted to turn off backlight' >> /home/lair001/cronout.txt
fi
}

# since cron jobs can only be scheduled up to
# once a minute, run CheckIdle twice with a 31s
# delay between iterations

CheckIdle
echo 'Ran first check' >> /home/lair001/cronout.txt
sleep 31s
CheckIdle
echo 'Ran second check' >> /home/lair001/cronout.txt
```

The cron file for root is as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * /usr/bin/thinpad_kb_bl_dr_idl.sh & >/dev/null 2>&1
```

From the cron logs, it appears as though the command is running:

```
Aug  4 23:25:01 Robotron CRON[5310]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/thinpad_kb_bl_dr_idl.sh & >/dev/null 2>&1)
Aug  4 23:26:01 Robotron CRON[5396]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/thinpad_kb_bl_dr_idl.sh & >/dev/null 2>&1)
Aug  4 23:27:01 Robotron CRON[5399]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/thinpad_kb_bl_dr_idl.sh & >/dev/null 2>&1)
Aug  4 23:28:01 Robotron CRON[5452]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/thinpad_kb_bl_dr_idl.sh & >/dev/null 2>&1)
Aug  4 23:29:01 Robotron CRON[5459]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/thinpad_kb_bl_dr_idl.sh & >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

However, cronout.txt remains empty.  The script runs properly as sudo or root from the terminal.  Originally, I tried to implement this script as a persistent background process, but it kept stopping:

```
# !/bin/sh

# requires installation of xprintidle

while true
do
    # if user idle for greater than or equal to 30s and
    # keyboard backlight is on, turn backlight off
    if [ 30000 -le $(xprintidle) ] && [ $(cat /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness) -ne 0 ]
        then
        echo '0' > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
    # else if user pressed a key within the past 30s and
    # keyboard backlight is off, put backlight on dim
    elif [ 30000 -gt $(xprintidle) ] && [ $(cat /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness) -eq 0 ]
        then
        echo '1' > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
    fi
    # Check every 2 seconds
    # Faster check cycles means that the backlight turns on
    # quicker after keystroke at the expense of
    # greater CPU and power consumption
    sleep 2s
done
```

Still want to implement a way to turn on the keyboard backlight with user activity after I've found a way past the permissions issues and dying infinite loops.

Comment: Alright, turns out there was a spelling error in the crontab file:  thinpad instead of thinkpad.   Now we have the problem that the if statement is never executed even when the user is idle for long periods of time and the keyboard backlight is on.  The script works properly when run from a terminal.

Comment: cat is in /bin and xprintidle is in /usr/bin.  Both of these are in the script's path.  Are there any libraries that need to be included for if statement functionality?

Comment: Changed shebang to !#/bin/bash to no avail.